# TypeError: Object of type Tag is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, django, list

I am trying to send my result as `JsonResponse` but when I run the function then it is showing every time

> TypeError: Object of type Tag is not JSON serializable

views.py

```
def saveJson(request):
    response = getReturnedData()

    results = []

    for result in response:
        results.append({'json': result})

    return JsonResponse({'results': results})
```

returned data from `getReturnedData()` is :-

> **Note :-** "Image1" is not the real data I got in list BUT it is a `link` of `image` url (not string), I didn't post it because stackoverflow was showing `spam` while posting img links

```
[
    "Image1", 
    "Image1"
]
```

converted from for loop is :-

```
[
    {
        'response': [
                       "Image1", 
                       "Image2"
                     ]
    }
]
```

I have also tried by using `json.dumps` but it returns nothing

And I also tried using **data = serializers.serialize("json", results)** but it showed

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'concrete_model

I have tried hours but it didn't work, Any help would be much Appreciated. Thank You in Advance

Comment: Could you show the actual type (the model class) of the values "image1", "image2"? Have you created a serializer for this type ? https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

Comment: I am not using this in `django rest framework` , I am extracting these links `BeautifulSoup` and I am looking a way to convert these serializeable

Comment: There are not enough details to figure it out. Check [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Long shot: what if `response = list(getReturnedData())`?

Comment: @CristiFati, It returns a list, But i try to convert `list to json` by **json.dumps()** then it is showing `Object of type Tag is not JSON serializable`

Comment: Then `results.append({'json': str(result)})`?